# SearchCursor is outside tuple range despite having multiple fields in the parameter

Tags: arcpy, cursor, indexerror

In the below script, I get an error on line that starts with `insertRow` that says IndexError: tuple index out of range.

```
outputLocation = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
nullPntFc = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
outPolyPath = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)

arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(outputLocation, nullPntFc, "POINT")
arcpy.management.AddField(os.path.join(outputLocation, nullPntFc), "FC", "TEXT")
arcpy.management.AddField(os.path.join(outputLocation, nullPntFc), "FC_objectId", "LONG")
arcpy.management.AddField(os.path.join(outputLocation, nullPntFc), "AttributeMissing", "TEXT")


# Get the list of feature classes in the geodatabase
fcListLine = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("*Section", feature_dataset = "ARCFM.ElectricDataSet")
fcListPoint = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("*Transformer", feature_dataset = "ARCFM.ElectricDataSet") + arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("*Bank", feature_dataset = "ARCFM.ElectricDataSet") + arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("*Location", feature_dataset = "ARCFM.ElectricDataSet") 
fcListSelection = fcListLine + fcListPoint

for fc in fcListSelection:
    # Describe feature class to get attributes used in nullPntFc, nullPolylineFc, and nullPolygonFc.
    desc = arcpy.Describe(fc)
    fcName = desc.name
    fcType = desc.shapeType # Point, Polyline, Polygon
    arcpy.AddMessage(fcName + ' - '+ fcType)
    # get the field names to be used in the search cursor
    fieldNames = [field.name for field in arcpy.ListFields(fc) if field.name.endswith("FEEDERID") or field.name.endswith("LOCATIONID") or field.name.endswith("PHASINGCODE")] + ['SHAPE@XY']
    arcpy.AddMessage(fieldNames)
    # Get the shape field index from the list of fields.  The index will be used in the search cursor to pull the shape value
    fields = arcpy.ListFields(fc)
    for field in fields:
        if field.type == 'Geometry':
            shapeFieldIndex = fields.index(field)

    # Dump point features with null attributes in the point feature classes into nullPntFc
        if fcType == 'Point':
            count = 0
            while count < len(fieldNames) - 1:
                with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc,fieldNames) as sc:
                    for row in sc:
                        if row[0] == None or row[1] == None or row[2] == None:
                            arcpy.AddMessage(fieldNames)
                            fieldName = fieldNames[count]
                            insertCursor = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(os.path.join(outputLocation, nullPntFc), ('SHAPE@XY', 'FC', 'FC_objectId', 'AttributeMissing'))
                            insertRow = [row[shapeFieldIndex], fcName, str(row[0]), fieldName]
                            print(insertRow)
                            insertCursor.insertRow(insertRow)
                            del insertCursor
                count += 1
```

I know that the error is caused by the `row[shapeFieldIndex]` being outside the range of the SearchCursor, which has the parameter `fieldNames` that contains the fields I want to pass the loop through. I am not sure why the searchCursor is going outside the range of `fieldNames` when I defined multiple fields in it.

Comment: Nesting an InsertCursor inside a SearchCursor is counter to common usage (create it once, *outside* the search, and invoke `insertRow` as needed).  You should use the actual shape object (`'shape@'`) not the `@XY` (assuming the coordrefs are the same, which they should be). The `str.index()` isn't going to match actual to virtual field name -- just put them both first or last (using `len()-1` as index).  You could cut this down to a single fc iteration without the first score of lines to make the code sample less voluminous.

Comment: Your issue is likely caused by the fact you are determining the value for `shapeFieldIndex` based on all fields in the feature class, but you are trying to use that index value against a tuple returned from the search cursor where the order of fields in the search cursor does not match the order of fields in the feature class.  Looking at your search cursor definition, you are making the shape field the last field in the search cursor in position 3.